# angular-translate inside loop

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-translate

I'm trying to construct a translated message by looping over an array of objects and then adding a new "message" property to that object containing the translated string. I see the correct message output while inside $translate.then(); but when I assign the message to the object it is undefined. What is the correct way to resolve the promise returned from $translate.then() and assign it to the "message" property?

//items.controller.js

```
function getItems() {
    return itemsFactory.getItems()
    .then(function (response) {
        vm.items = initItemsList(response.activities);
    });
}

function initItemsList(itemsList) {
    for (var i = 0; i < itemsList.length; i++){
        var activityType = itemsList[i].activityType;

        switch (activityType){
            case "HISTORY": {
                var itemName = itemsList[i].item.itemName;
                var itemVersion = itemsList[i].item.itemVersion;
                $translate('activity.'+activityType, { itemname: itemName, itemversion: itemVersion }).then(function(content){
                    vm.itemContent = content;
                    console.log(vm.itemContent); // correct message displayed.
                });
                break;
            }
            default: {
                break;
            }
        }
        itemsList[i].message = vm.itemContent; // undefined
    }
    return itemsList;
}
```

// translation.json

```
"activity : {
    "HISTORY" : "History for {{ itemname }} {{ itemversion }}."
    }
```

Comment: Could it be that the last assignments appends before the promise resolves? What about moving the `itemList[i].message = ...` inside of the `.then( )...` part?

Comment: I tried this but only the last item's message gets set corrrectly. I can see all the messages printed to the console inside $translate.then() but only the last item's message is set.

Comment: @neridaj read http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572

Comment: Using the deferred method results in the same behavior i.e., only the last item of the loop is available inside $translate.then(). The loop is completing before the assignment happens, so itemList[i] is always the last item. I can see that inside $translate.then() that each translated message is assigned to the last item of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

As @Vegar correctly states, the code inside `then` is executed after the assignment so moving the assignment inside `then` function will take care of the problem. However, your `itemsList` will be returned from the function before all the translations are done so you will need to return a promise that resolves when all translations are done:

```
function initItemsList(itemsList) {
   var allTranslations = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < itemsList.length; i++){
      var activityType = itemsList[i].activityType;
      switch (activityType){
        case "HISTORY": {
            var itemName = itemsList[i].item.itemName;
            var itemVersion = itemsList[i].item.itemVersion;
              allTranslations.push($translate('activity.'+activityType, { itemname: itemName, itemversion: itemVersion }).then(function(content){
                vm.itemContent = content;
                itemsList[i].message = vm.itemContent;
            }));
            break;
        }
        default: {
              break;
           }
       }
   }
   return  $q.all(allTranslations);
}
```

The caller of your function will have to do like:

```
initItemList(itemList).then(function(translatedList){
     //Do stuff with translated list
});
```

Comment: [Why use a deferred?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) Also, `$q.all` does not take a callback.

Answer (score 0):

Promises are always resolved asynchronously. So the statement

```
itemsList[i].message = vm.itemContent;
```

, which is executed right after the switch, is executed before the callback passed to the $translate promise. Just move the statement to the callback:

```
$translate('activity.'+activityType, { itemname: itemName, itemversion: itemVersion }).then(function(content){
                vm.itemContent = content;
                console.log(vm.itemContent);
                itemsList[i].message = vm.itemContent;
            });
```